# Authentication for Proactive Message Endpoint

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, botframework, azure-web-app-service

I am building a Bot Framework bot which needs to be triggered proactively from an Azure Function. I have deployed a prototype to Azure based on [this example](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/python/16.proactive-messages) which currently allows me to `POST` to an `/api/notify` REST endpoint in order to send messages proactively.

However, I am not sure how to go about adding authentication to the `/api/notify` endpoint. Messages to the  `/api/messages` endpoint are authenticated using the Bot Service API in the application code, but in that example there is no authentication on traffic to the `/api/notify` endpoint (I can `POST` to it using `curl` from my CLI without any tokens or passphrases).

I tried enabling `App Service Authentication` on the underlying App Service but then my bot no longer worked in the web chat.

How do I add authentication to this endpoint so only my Azure Function can `POST` to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually just set this up for an internal project a couple of weeks ago. You'll probably need to adapt this strategy to whatever language your bot and function are in, but here's what I did:

**Azure Function**

```js
module.exports = class BotService {
    constructor(context) {
        this.context = context;
        // Get appId and password from environment variables to build credentials
        this.credentials = new MicrosoftAppCredentials(process.env.MicrosoftAppId, process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword);
        this.client = axios.create({
            baseURL: process.env.BotBaseUrl
        });
    }

    async sendData(body) {
        // Get the auth token using the credentials
        const token = await this.credentials.getToken();
        const response = await this.client.post('/api/data', body, {
            // Add the token to the auth header
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${ token }` }
        });
        if (response.status !== 200) {
            this.context.error(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
        } else {
            this.context.log(`Successfully sent data to the bot. Response Code: ${ response.status }`);
        }
    }
}
```

**Bot**  *Note: The bot is in C# and this is in the controller for `/api/data`*

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpStatusCode> PostAsync()
{
    try
    {
        // Build the bot credentials
        var credentials = new SimpleCredentialProvider(Configuration["MicrosoftAppId"], Configuration["MicrosoftAppPassword"]);
        // Grab the auth header from the request
        Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out StringValues authHeader);
        // Use Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.JwtTokenValidation to validate the auth header
        var result = await JwtTokenValidation.ValidateAuthHeader(authHeader, credentials, new SimpleChannelProvider(), Channels.Directline);

        if (result.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // Do stuff
            // Do stuff
            return HttpStatusCode.OK;
        }

        return HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.LogError($"Something went wrong in /api/data controller: {e.Message}");
    }
    return HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
}
```

It looks like your bot is in Python. You can see [similar auth validation in one of our Python tests](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-python/blob/e5254b6580805adcc1682fe2fdafc972e4036a14/libraries/botframework-connector/tests/test_auth.py#L27)

Comment: Excellent answer, the Python parallels were pretty easy to find.

Comment: @evan.oman Oh good! Glad you found it and thanks for the additional rep!